# Проверка данных из формы работает некорректно JS

Tags: javascript, html, валидация, формы

Есть код:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.final');
const paragraph = document.querySelector('.answer');
const kk = document.querySelector('.k').value;
const nn = document.querySelector('.n').value;

const summ = () => {
  const kk = document.querySelector('.k').value;
  const nn = document.querySelector('.n').value;
  const multiplication = k * n;
  return multiplication;
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (typeof(kk) !== 'number' || typeof(nn) !== 'number' || kk < 0 || nn < 0) {
    paragraph.innerHTML = 'Enter valid numbers';
  } else {
    paragraph.innerHTML = summ();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="k">
<input type="text" class="n">
<input type="submit" class="final">
<p class="answer">
```

Результат он вписывает, но игнорирует мою проверку if-else на `тип данных` и ввод `> 0`.

В чем я ошибся?

Comment: Этот код не работает, чтобы он заработал, можно обернуть переменные kk и nn  в Number, вот так: const kk = Number(document.querySelector('.k').value);

Comment: Но проверка все равно не работает для отрицательных и текста

Comment: `typeof` - оператор, не функция, кстати. Можно без скобок) Они не мешают, но ничего и не делают.

Answer (score 4):

```
const kk = document.querySelector('.k').value;
const nn = document.querySelector('.n').value;
```

Эти значения получаете один раз, во время запуска скрипта (когда input-ы еще пустые, оба будут `""`) - каждый раз они и идут на проверку. Оба являются строками (даже если в HTML изначально будут числовые значения), поэтому и проходят сравнение `!== "number"` (строка - не число).

А почему функция умножает, а называется "sum" ?

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const answer = document.querySelector('.answer');
const k = document.querySelector('.k');
const n = document.querySelector('.n');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  answer.textContent = validate_n_mul(k.value, n.value);
  
  /***/                 
  function validate_n_mul(str_1, str_2) {
    if (
      !str_1 || !str_2 ||     // пустая строка
      isNaN(str_1 + str_2) || // где-то ввели не число
      str_1 < 0 || str_2 < 0  // меньше нуля
    ) return 'Enter valid numbers';

    return str_1 * str_2;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="k">
<input type="text" class="n">
<input type="submit" class="button">
<p class="answer">
```

`str_1 < 0` — при сравнении строки с числом, строка тоже неявно будет преобразована в числовой тип. Но если оба - строки, `"11" < "9"` выдаст true. С этим нужно быть осторожным (заранее превращать их в число).

Comment: Допустил ошибку: Может сложиться такая ситуация: `isNaN("1" + "-1")` — строки приклеятся. А строка `"1-1"` и правда будет NaN. Но т.к вам нужно чтобы числа еще и были положительным, это здесь не мешает. Но правильнее было бы использовать `-`: `"1" - "-1"` → `2` (минус преобразует операнды в числа). А по хорошему, вообще сперва проверить прилетевшие строки на пустоту (или пробелы), превратить их в числа, и дальше нормально делать проверки именно с числами. Я гнался за короткой проверкой)

Answer (score 3):

Вы были очень близко, я чуть доработал Вашу логику:

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".final")
const paragraph = document.querySelector(".answer")
const k = document.querySelector(".k")
const n = document.querySelector(".n")

const summ = (kk, nn) => {
  return kk * nn
}

const handleClick = () => {
  const kk = Number(k.value.trim())
  const nn = Number(n.value.trim())
  if (isNaN(kk) || kk < 0 || isNaN(nn) || nn < 0) {
  // или
  // if (isNaN(kk) || isNaN(nn)) {}
  // если проверка на отрицательные цисла не требуется
    paragraph.innerHTML = "Enter valid numbers"
  } else {    
    paragraph.innerHTML = summ(kk, nn)
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", handleClick)
```

```html
<input type="text" class="k" />
<input type="text" class="n" />
<input type="submit" class="final" />
<p class="answer"></p>
```

*Отдельно стоит отметить что если данные `input'ы` должны принимать только числа, то стоит задать им тип "number", что позволит избежать дополнительных проверок на тип впоследствии:*

```
<input type="number" />
```